# IdentityServer4- Challenge ALL requests to API not just [Authorize]

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an ASP.Net Core 2 API using IdentityServer4. I would like challenge ALL requests to the server and invoke the login redirect if the user is not authenticated, calling back to a specific URL after authentication.

The default is to invoke the login redirect only when an unauthenticated user requests a resource protected by the [Authorize] attribute. This will not work in my use case.

Basically, I want the functional equivalent of an [Authorize] attribute for the whole application not just specific controllers.

What is the easiest way to do this? Is there a setting I can use when configuring the services in Startup.cs (services.AddAuthentication)? Or through custom middleware right after app.UseAuthentication()?

I tried the following custom middleware but it says a handler is not configured.

ConfigureServices

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://localhost:4000";
                options.ApiName = "myapi";
            });
```

Configure

```
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
               await context.ChallengeAsync(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties {RedirectUri= "https://localhost:5000/" });
            }
            else { await next.Invoke(); }
        });

        app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: Typically you’d not want an API like this to do anything other than return a 401 and then leave it up to the client to obtain a valid token. What’s the full desired flow here?

Comment: @mackie agreed 100%. In this specific use case, I have been given the requirement of protecting all requests to the API and redirecting users that are not authenticated.

Comment: This might help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-2.1#require-authenticated-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For configuring `[Authorize]` for the whole controllers, you could try `AuthorizeFilter` like below

```
            services.AddMvc(config => {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                     .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                     .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                })                    
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

For redirecting, you could try configure `UserInteraction.LoginUrl`

```
            services.AddIdentityServer(opt => {
                    opt.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Identity/Account/LogIn";
                })
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>();
```