# Protecting static files with Authorization Middleware using IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a IS4 set up and most of the clients that use it get their pictures from a simple ASP.NET Core API. There is one method for adding pictures that go to wwwroot. 
I noticed that, while unauthorized users can't add new pictures, anyone can access the pictures if they know the URL. After a quick search, i found out that i need a middleware to protect static files, so i shamelessly used sir Alan's code from [here](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/10/06/authorization-policies-and-middleware-in-asp-net-5.aspx). 
After modifying it for ASP.NET Core (unsure if i did it correctly), i couldn't get authorized from any of the clients (I would get a 401 response, so at least that works correctly).
Here are the services added:

```
services.AddAuthentication(
            IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://some.url";
                options.ApiName = "SomeAPI";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Authenticated", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser());
        });
```

And the Invoke method from ProtectFolder, that i modifyied:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext,
                             IAuthorizationService authorizationService, 
                             IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
    {
        if (httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(_path))
        {
            var authenticated = await authenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(httpContext, 
                IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var authorized = await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(httpContext.User, null, _policyName);
            if (!authorized.Succeeded)
            {
                await authenticationService.ChallengeAsync(httpContext,
                    IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, authenticated.Properties);
                return;
            }
        }

        await _next(httpContext);
    }
```

So i managed to protect the files, but now I can't access them either. Since I'm using IS4 I'm pretty sure I need to use the token for authorization, but I'm unsure how.

I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52957531/how-to-protect-static-folder-in-asp-net-core-2-1-using-claims-based-authorizatio) and put UseAuthentication above UseProtectFolder and UseStaticFiles, but I still get a 401 response. I also checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52503566/identityserver4-challenge-all-requests-to-api-not-just-authorize), but I'm unsure if it will help, since I'm not using the controller to get the files.

Comment: How are the files accessed? Via browser (i.e. as part of a html website)? If so, you can't protect it with IdSrv4 as it is, since it provides only a token which is passed via `Authorization` header to the website and browser don't support that, you'd need cookie authentication for that, but that's kinda in practical with WebAPI/Restful Api, since well... you never visit an webapi in the browser and authentication works differently

Comment: On Mvc apps you try to access a resource and get redirected to the login page and sign in, then get redirected back and the cookie is set. For restful apis the client gets redirected to Identity provider, logs in, gets redirected back with a token which is then passed to the resource server with each request

Comment: Additionally, if you grow in your application you don't even want your application to host the files but use CDN instead. protecting CDN content is next to impossible (which is why facebook, instagram & co) don't protect their uploaded content. Its public, but with long cryptic urls which are impossible to guess. But if you know the url you can access it from everywhere

Comment: It's only an API, it doesn't have a UI, with only a single controller with a method to add pics to wwwroot/Image. Since it's running on the dev server, pics are accessed by going to URL like http://ServerURL:PORT/Image/ImageName.png

Comment: Yeah since the client isn't sending a request, it isn't sending a token either, I guess. I could generate a GUID name for the img files for now and it should be a bit better then. Or could I maybe block all access to wwwroot, and return img files via a method in the controller or something like that? @Tseng

Comment: You could, but same problem. Token needs to be passed in the header or via cookie, so you're back at square one :P